# How to extract characters from file names in a directory?

Tags: python

Essentially, if I have a file:

```
"Field_20130515-212300"
```

I want to extract the date `20130515-212300`. I have a method, but it is inelegant. Just wondering if there's a better way to do this.

```
times = os.listdir("path\\to\\your\\file")
for idx, time in enumerate(times):
    time[idx] = time[-15:]
```

Comment: `time.split("_")[1]` or `time.split("Field_")[0]`??

Comment: Calling the variable `time` could create issues if you later find that you need to import the `time` module.

Comment: @AmiHollander The first method works, only it's time.split("_")[1]. I was mostly hoping to just avoid the for loop though.

Comment: @alani yea I've been lazy in my code. I could just call it t.

Comment: Actually what *exactly* are you trying to do? Create a new list? It looks *possibly* like you want something like `timestamps = [filename.split('_')[1] for filename in os.listdir(......)]`

Comment: @alani. I see (maybe). it would look like ```times = [t.split("_")[1] for t in times]```. Yes, I am creating a new list so I can search through it.

Comment: If you want to search through it, you might want to consider whether you care about the order or not. If not, then you might want to use a set (quicker to search). Same syntax except with outer `{...}` instead of `[...]`

Comment: Interesting. It's only like 100 items at max, so that's not necessary. But I'll keep that in mind. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems simple to do it in a one liner..

```
import os
times = [file[-15:] for file in os.listdir('path\\to\\your\\file')]
```

Or with split()

```
import os
times = [file.split('_')[1] for file in os.listdir('path\\to\\your\\file')]
```

Comment: He is asking for a better solution. 
is one-liner is better solution?
are you comparing code visuality with quality really?

Comment: @SuryaveerSingh Actually, I was looking for the shortest (i.e. minimum lines) to do this. I like my code to be simple and direct. It's aesthetics.

Comment: Edited one is right which you did after comment, but simply converting code to list comprehension is not a good solution.

Comment: Why is that? It essentially does the same thing that I was doing, but in fewer characters.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved using list comprehension thanks to @alani.

```
times = os.listdir("path\\to\\your\\file")
times = [t.split("_")[1] for t in times]
```

Comment: Probably doesn't matter here, but this would fail if there were any other underscores in the file path. I think using -1 for the index, to get the last element, would be a little better

Comment: I agree, actually. Thanks for the input.